# Rename Object Keys from Snake Case to Camel Case Recursively Without Using Lodash

Tags: javascript

How to recursively convert object keys from snake case to camel case using plain javascript without relying on external libraries such as Lodash. Below is an attempt that only works for first level of the object. What's the best way to do this?

```
const obj = {
  key_first: 'firstVal',
  key_second: 'secondVal',
  key_third: null,
  nested_obj: {
    nested_one: 'nested 1 value',
    nested_two: 'nested 2 value'
  },
  nested_arr: [{
    nested_obj_one: 'nested obj val 1'
  }, {
    nested_obj_two: 'nested obj val 2'
  }, {
    level_3_nested: [{
      level_3_key: 'level 3 value',
      level_3_another_key: 'another level 3 value'
    }]
  }]
};
```

```
const renameKeys = obj => Object
  .entries(obj)
  .reduce((acc, [key, val]) => {
    const modifiedKey = key.replace(/_([a-z])/g, g =>  g[1].toUpperCase());
    return ({
      ...acc,
      ...{ [modifiedKey]: val },
    });
  }, {});
```

```
console.log(renameKeys(obj));
```

**Update:** Added key with value of null.

Comment: Hi, Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73220750/11888809 , you can do this in one line of code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd `.map` the `Object.entries`, replacing the key in the entry, while recursively calling `renamekeys` on the value, and pass the whole array entry to `Object.fromEntries` to turn it back into an object.

Since you have nested arrays too, not just nested objects. you'll have to test for them and `.map` each item via `renameKeys` if found.

You also probably want to tweak the regex so that *all* underscores get replaced, not just those followed by alphabetical characters:

```js
const obj = {
  key_first: 'firstVal',
  key_second: 'secondVal',
  nested_obj: {
    nested_one: 'nested 1 value',
    nested_two: 'nested 2 value'
  },
  nested_arr: [{
    nested_obj_one: 'nested obj val 1'
  }, {
    nested_obj_two: 'nested obj val 2'
  }, {
    level_3_nested: [{
      level_3_key: 'level 3 value',
      level_3_another_key: 'another level 3 value'
    }]
  }]
};

const processVal = val => (
  typeof val !== 'object'
  ? val
  : Array.isArray(val)
    ? val.map(renameKeys)
    : renameKeys(val)
);
const renameKeys = obj => Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj)
    .map(([key, val]) => [
      key.replace(/_(.)/g, g =>  g[1].toUpperCase()),
      processVal(val)
    ])
);
console.log(renameKeys(obj));
```

To permit `null` values as well:

```js
const obj = {
  key_first: 'firstVal',
  key_second: 'secondVal',
  nested_obj: {
    nested_one: 'nested 1 value',
    nested_two: 'nested 2 value'
  },
  nested_arr: [{
    nested_obj_one: 'nested obj val 1'
  }, {
    nested_obj_two: 'nested obj val 2'
  }, {
    level_3_nested: [{
      level_3_key: 'level 3 value',
      level_3_another_key: 'another level 3 value'
    }]
  }]
};

const processVal = val => (
  (typeof val !== 'object' || val === null)
  ? val
  : Array.isArray(val)
    ? val.map(renameKeys)
    : renameKeys(val)
);
const renameKeys = obj => Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj)
    .map(([key, val]) => [
      key.replace(/_(.)/g, g =>  g[1].toUpperCase()),
      processVal(val)
    ])
);
console.log(renameKeys(obj));
```

If the arrays can be on the first level, then use `val.map(processVal)` in `processVal`, and first call `processVal` instead of `renameKeys`:

```js
const obj = {
  simple_arr: ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'],
  key_first: 'firstVal',
  key_second: 'secondVal',
  nested_obj: {
    nested_one: 'nested 1 value',
    nested_two: 'nested 2 value'
  },
  nested_arr: [{
    nested_obj_one: 'nested obj val 1'
  }, {
    nested_obj_two: 'nested obj val 2'
  }, {
    level_3_nested: [{
      level_3_key: 'level 3 value',
      level_3_another_key: 'another level 3 value'
    }]
  }]
};

const processVal = val => (
  (typeof val !== 'object' || val === null)
  ? val
  : Array.isArray(val)
    ? val.map(processVal)
    : renameKeys(val)
);
const renameKeys = obj => Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj)
    .map(([key, val]) => [
      key.replace(/_(.)/g, g =>  g[1].toUpperCase()),
      processVal(val)
    ])
);
console.log(processVal(obj));
```

Comment: Great answer! It errors out when one of the object keys has a value `null`. How to work around it?

Comment: Just add `|| val === null`

Comment: that works! From testing, I discovered that it has unintended consequence when handling a simple array at the first level of nesting. It turns `simple_arr: ['a1', 'b1', 'c1']` into `simpleArr: {"0":"a1","1":"b1","2":"c1"}`.

Comment: See 3rd snippet, use `val.map(processVal)`

Answer (score 0):

Add recursive call for nested object

```
const renameKeys = obj => Object
  .entries(obj)
  .reduce((acc, [key, val]) => {
    const modifiedKey = key.replace(/_([a-z])/g, g =>  g[1].toUpperCase());
    const modifiedVal = typeof val === 'object' && val !== null ? 
        renameKeys(val) : val;
    return ({
      ...acc,
      ...{ [modifiedKey]: modifiedVal },
    });
  }, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for..in` something like this

```js
const obj = {key_first: 'firstVal',key_second: 'secondVal',nested_obj: {nested_one: 'nested 1 value',nested_two: 'nested 2 value'},nested_arr: [{nested_obj_one: 'nested obj val 1'}, {nested_obj_two: 'nested obj val 2'}, {level_3_nested: [{level_3_key: 'level 3 value',level_3_another_key: 'another level 3 value'}]}]};

let keyChanger = (obj) => {
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
        obj[key].map(v => keyChanger(v))
      } else {
        keyChanger(obj[key])
      }
    }
    const modifiedKey = key.replace(/_([a-z])/g, g => g[1].toUpperCase());
    obj[modifiedKey] = obj[key]
    delete obj[key]
  }
  return obj
}

console.log(keyChanger(obj))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this method of camelizing nested object keys will save lot of iterations.

```js
const camelizeNestedKeys = function(dataObj) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dataObj).trim().replace(/("\w+":)/g, function(keys) {
        return keys.replace(/(.(\_|-|\s)+.)/g, function(subStr) {
            return subStr[0]+(subStr[subStr.length-1].toUpperCase());
        })
    }));
}


const data = {
    'id':'123',
    'employee_name': 'John',
    'employee_type': 'new'  
};

const nestedData = {
    'id':'123',
    'employee_name': 'John',
    'employee_type': 'new',
    'exployee_projects': [
        {"project_name": "test1", "project_year": 2004},
        {"project_name": "test2", "project_year": 2004}
    ]
};

console.log(camelizeNestedKeys(data));

console.log(camelizeNestedKeys(nestedData));
```