# How can I copy a key of a tree structure to a key with another name or rename it to something else?

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can I copy a key of a tree structure to a key with another name or rename it to something else?

**From this:**

```
[
   {
      "title":"testing",
      "id":1,
      "children":[
         {
            "title":"Preamble",
            "id":2
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

**To this:**

```
[
   {
      "title":"testing",
      "label":"testing",
      "id":1,
      "key":1,
      "children":[
         {
            "title":"Preamble",
            "label":"Preamble",
            "id":2,
            "key":2
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

in this one the label is a copy of title and the the key a copy of id.

**or this:**

```
[
   {
      "label":"testing",
      "key":1,
      "children":[
         {
            "label":"Preamble",
            "key":2
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

in this one the title is renamed to label and the id to key.

The tree structure can have a lot nodes / children.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: Object Rename Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key)

Comment: Or [Rename Object Keys from Snake Case to Camel Case Recursively Without Using Lodash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58257467/215552)

Comment: @HereticMonkey it does the job for a single key in an object, but I need it for a tree structure which means somehow we have to traverse through it's nodes and do the changes. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: And the second link? Also, you could just call the first one recursively...

Comment: @HereticMonkey the second link is more promising, I just need to see how it can work for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a mapping function which maps the children as well.

```js
const
    newStructure = ({ title, label = title, id, key = id, children }) => ({
        title, label, id, key,
        ...(children && { children: children.map(newStructure) })
    }),
    data = [{ title: "testing", id: 1, children: [{ title: "Preamble", id: 2 }] }],
    result = data.map(newStructure);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```